# javascript not working from network drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, jquery-ui

I'm trying to run the below file. It runs perfectly fine when I run it on a local drive but if I place it on a network drive it no longer works. Any idea why this might be?

The below is code that I am trying to run. It is using pivottable from here: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Demo</title>
    <!-- external libs from cdnjs -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PivotTable.js libs from ../dist -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/pivot.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/pivot.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {font-family: Verdana;}
    </style>

    <!-- optional: mobile support with jqueryui-touch-punch -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
// This example shows custom aggregators using 


$(function(){
    var tpl = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates;

    $.getJSON("col.json", function(frontier) {
        $("#output").pivotUI(frontier, {
            rows: ["Manager"], cols: ["Sector"],
            aggregators: {
                "Number of Positions":      function() { return tpl.count()() },
                "Manager Weight": function() { return tpl.sum()(["Port"])},
                "Benchmark XGCC Weight": function() { return tpl.sum()(["Bench"])},
            }
        });
    });
 });
    </script>



    <div id="output" style="margin: 30px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you also put `../dist/pivot.js` and `../dist/pivot.css` on the network drive? Do you get any errors in the brower's console or network tab?

Comment: Are you moving your entire project to the network drive, or just this file. You have relative paths to your script/css files.

Comment: Running JavaScript off of a file protocol has different security settings. Are there any error messages in the console? Do you see any 404s in the network tab?

Comment: Not an issue with moving the project folder. Issue goes away when I run original files but for some reason when I re-save them even without modifying the text the files do not work. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`File:///` urls will run in a different context than HTTP/HTTPS and other contexts (internal, public, private, unsafe).  What limitations in question depend on the specific browser, the OS and the context itself.

If you *must* execute JavaScript within HTML, the safest and most assured way to run is to have it running via a web server.

---

Also worth noting, there are a few local/relative files. `../dist/pivot.js` and `../dist/pivot.css` are you sure you're saving those files, and they are in the correct relative path as well?

Comment: I can run original code written from the pivot tables example library in I.E. The issue seems to be when I open the original code and and re-save a copy of it. If I do this, even if I make no changes, the new file will not run when stored on a network drive and run from File or on IIS. However, if I right click and copy the original html files (even changing their names) then it works. I've tried making modifications to the files in eclipse, VS Code, wordpad, notepad, etc and whenever I re-save I am no longer able to get the html file to work. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: The file is including scripts from https:// from cloudflare... again, certain things don't work from filesystems, and it will depend on where you are saving, which browser you are using and your security settings...  there's also relative files for ../dist/... that you may not be copying over.